# how to get the posts of a particular category from slug name when passing through url in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a link with me. This is the link:

http://localhost/rajab/product-category/pvc-hose/

I have made a a category "PVC Hose" having slug name "pvc-hose" and displayed on a page. when i am clicking this category, it goes to a link as shown above.i wanted to display all the posts in this category on linked page. Can anyone say how to display it there.

Comment: i think that is default in wp .add some posts in that category they shows in this page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a `taxonomy.php` file in your root folder with the following code

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

        // Your markup and template tags like
       the_title();
       echo '</br>';

     }
}
```

Comment: i have created the taxonomy-taxonomyslug.php file..i have written this code in that..

Answer (score 0):

```
          <li class="cbp-item houses cbp-l-grid-masonry-height1">
                            <a class="cbp-caption cbp-lightbox" data-title="PVC Air Hose" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/buiding/pvc/img1.jpg">
                                <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/buiding/pvc/img1.jpg" alt="">
                                </div>

                            </a>
                            <h4><?php $data->post_title; ?></h4>
                    </li>
```

i wanted to repeat this code in  the taxonomy file..I wanted to display not only the title and content but also featured image.